# What does it mean by renormalization of a vector?

Tags: c, vector, normalization

I have a vector which I need to renormalize according to the algorithm,

for example, in C if I have the following,

```
double V[4] = {1,2,3,4};
```

The algorithm says I need to renormalize the vector V and I have no idea what that means,

I found this link while I was researching but I don't understand it either...

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19041/when-and-why-is-r-sumr-not-a-good-way-to-renormalize-a-vector-in-pagerank-c

Could someone please help

Comment: Usually normalizing the vector means making the size of it equal one. Calculate the size of the vector (square root of the sum of each element's square) and divide every element by the size.

Comment: I believe that is more correctly called length, not size, of a vector. Size, in turn, is the number of components in a vector.

Comment: if I were to normalize this vector I'd find the length which is square root of sum all the elements squared. But if you follow the link included... it just divides each element by sum(vector) which I don't really get why..